# Schema migration in Redis

Tags: redis

I have an application using redis. I used a key name `user:<id>` to store user info. Then locally I changed my app code to use key name `user:<id>:data` for that purpose.

I am scared by the fact that if I git push this new code to my production server things will break. And the reason for this is that since my production redis server would already have the keys will older key names.

So the only way I think is to stop my app, change all the older key names to new ones & then restart it. Do you have a better alternative? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing new code to your production environment is always a scary business (that's why only the toughest survive in this profession ;)). I strongly recommend that before you change your production code and database, make sure that you test the workflow and its results locally.

Almost any update to the application requires its stoppage - even if only to replace the relevant files. This is even truer for any changes that involve a database exactly because of the reason you had mentioned.

Even if you can deploy your code changes without stopping the application per se (e.g. a PHP page), you will still want the database change to be done "atomically" - i.e. without any application requests intervening and possibly breaking. While some database can be taken offline for maintenance, even then you usually stop the app or else errors will be generated all over the place.

If that is indeed the case, you'll be stopping the app (or putting it into maintenance mode) regardless of the database change, so we take your question to actually mean: what's the fastest way to rename all/some keys in my database?

To answer that question, similarly to the pseudo-code suggested above, I suggest you use a Lua script such as the following and EVAL it once you stop the app:

```
for _,k in ipairs(redis.call('keys', 'user:*')) do 
    if k:sub(-5) ~= ':data' then 
        redis.call('rename', k, k .. ':data')
    end
end
```

A few notes about this script that you should keep in mind:

1. Although the KEYS command is not safe to use in production, since you are doing maintenance it can be used safely. For all other use cases where you need to scan you keys, Redis' SCAN is much more advisable.
2. Since Lua scripts are "atomic", you can in theory run this script without stopping the app - as long as the script runs (which depends on the size of your dataset) the app's requests will be blocked. Put differently, this approach solves the concern of getting mixed key names (old & new). This, however, is probably not what you'd want to do in any case because a) your app may still error/timeout during that time but mainly because b) it will need to be able to handle both types of key names (i.e. running with old keys -> short/long pause -> running with new keys) making your code much more complex.
3. The `if` condition is not required if you're going to run the script only once and succeed.
4. Depending on the actual contents of your database, you may want to further filter out keys that should not be renamed.
5. To ensure compatibility, refrain from hardcoding / computationally generating key names - instead, they should be passed as arguments to the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a migration script in your redis client language, using [RENAME](http://redis.io/commands/rename).

If you don't have any other control over the total of keys, you first issue a `KEYS user:*` to list all keys, then substring for getting the numeric id, then renaming.

You can issue all of this in a [transaction](http://redis.io/commands/multi).

So a little pseudocode and redis commands:

```
MULTI
KEYS user:*
For each key {
    id = <Get id from key>
    RENAME user:id user:id:data
}
EXEC
```

Got it ?